# I need help on this code

Tags: solidity, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

I have few question:

1.

```
bool zeroForOne = params.tokenIn < params.tokenOut;
```

This code means: if `params.tokenIn` is less than `params.tokenOut` then make `zeroForOne` true, am i right?

2.
There is a library named `Path.sol` in **libraries** directory, it has a function named `numPools()`. In a contract this library was imported and used for`bytes`, `using Path for bytes`, how this code is working then:

```
sqrtPriceX96AfterList = new uint160[](path.numPools());
```

we are imported **Path.sol** but how **path** came in `path.numPools()`? Should not it be `Path.numPools()`?

3.
A code is :

```
import "./libraries/Path.sol"
contract Check {
    using Path for bytes;
    struct SwapCallbackData {
        bytes path; // swap path
        address payer; // address who provides inout token in swaps
    }
    function _swap(
    uint256 amountIn,
    address recipient,
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96,
    SwapCallbackData memory data
    ) internal returns (uint256 amountOut) {
    
    
    (address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint24 tickSpacing) = data
    .path
    .decodeFirstPool();
  }
}
```

Here `decodeFirstPool()` is a function of **Path.sol** library, how `data.path.decodeFirstPool()` is working? I asked about the **path** in question 2, i am confused on how the connection was made between **data** and **path**??

Comment: Hi, please check the [help] on how what's the expected question format. Please keep to one question per post and use informative titles.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers:

1. Yes, you're correct `bool zeroForOne` would be true if `params.tokenIn` is greater than `params.tokenOut`.
2. as the **path** is of type **bytes**, when you call `path.numPools()` is actually calling the **numPools()** function from the Path library.
3. as **data.path** is of type **bytes** which is using **Path** library you can call the **decodeFirstPool()** function of **Path** Liberary.

P.S. `using Path for bytes;` creates a linkage between the **Path** library and the **bytes** data type.

Comment: Where the **path** [ small letter `p` ] came from?? i did not initialize **path** anywhere, it is *Path* not *path*.

Comment: can you share the code inside Path.sol or the full code where `sqrtPriceX96AfterList = new uint160[](path.numPools()); ` is.?

Comment: It is project related, so i can't, but i described everything

Comment: I suppose the **path** variable is being defined there, can you make sure?